# How can I speed up this function?

Tags: python, pygame

This check for if some points are inside a rectangle, and whenever it's run it slows my program down a lot. How can we change it to make it more efficient?

```
def draw_grid(self, box):
    for element in self.map_layout.all_map_objects:
        if element not in self.build_grid and box.area.collidepoint(element.checkpoint):
            self.build_grid.append(element)
        elif not box.area.collidepoint(element.checkpoint):
            if element in self.build_grid:
                self.build_grid.remove(element)
```

Comment: Does the order of `build_grid` matter?

Comment: Then I would definitely consider changing `self.build_grid` to a set (provided the elements that it contains are hashable)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One change which is trivial to make is to store the result of `box.area.collidepoint`:

```
def draw_grid(self, box):
    for element in self.map_layout.all_map_objects:
        collidepoint = box.area.collidepoint(element.checkpoint)
        if element not in self.build_grid and collidepoint:
            self.build_grid.append(element)
        elif not collidepoint:
            if element in self.build_grid:
                self.build_grid.remove(element)
```

Other changes rely on the data structure that you need.  For example, `self.build_grid` seems to be a `list`.  `__contains__` (in operator) on a list is **an O(N) operation** on average whereas if you could get by with a `set`, **it would be O(1)!**.  The same thing goes with `list.remove` -- Here you could use a `try-except` clause to remove one O(N) operation from the tight loop which might help if the element is *usually* in the list:

```
        elif not collidepoint:
            try:
                self.build_grid.remove(element)
            except ValueError:
                pass
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you check for collisions and the like only when elements are moved, rather than while drawing?

Also, you're invoking both `box.area.collidepoint(element.checkpoint):` and `element in self.build_grid:` possibly twice, once for the if, the other time for the elseif. Could you cache that answer if it's computationally expensive?

Comment: box.area is bound to mouse position, and when draw_grid is active we have to follow mouse movement.

Answer (score 1):

If you keep these points in some sorted data structure, you won't need to check every single one. Sort by Y, find all in your rectangle's Y range, then sort that new list by X, and find all in your rectangle's X range.

Comment: If I understand this, then that's exactly what the pygame function collidepoint does.

Comment: I think he's referencing a quadtree, which is different. It reduces the total amount of possible collisions to start with.